# My company moves to sharepoint 2013, must I be a sharepoint developer?

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I'm a web developer. My company moves to Sharepoint and wants to form a WAN in my country. So, our applications will be single sign on using LDAP. I want to learn that, must I be a sharepoint developer to publish my asp .net projects, or can I publish my asp .net projects(MVC or webforms) directly to Sharepoint server.

I'm confused because, I don't want to use sharepoint web parts, because I think it is very hard to write any custom complex web part using sharepoint dlls. So, I want to write my projects without using sharepoint dlls and publish it to sharepoint server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're in the target audience for the new SharePoint App model. This is where you can build your app as you please, and you build a kind of 'frame' around it which allows it to talk to SharePoint, and allows users in SharePoint to access it.

This method of development is quite new (even for us seasoned SharePoint developers), so extensive tutorials and documentation are sparse, but there is already quite a lot of documentation to get you started on MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/apps/jj220030.aspx) and there are also quite a few books out there (search on Amazon for SharePoint 2013 App Model).

Comment: Does this model give me chance to publish mvc project? And, what is cons and pros? Thanks for answer.